# Unable to launch the actual Application,but loads helloworld

Tags: java, android, mobile, automation, appium

After running my script, I am getting the screen shown here:

[image]

When i am trying to actually launch the selenroid app, can anyone please let me know why the app that i have called from the following script is not launching?

## testthis.java code(under second package name):

```
package demolaunchtest;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class testthis {
public static AndroidDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
public void setUP() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Lokesh Gangaiah");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0");


    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "io.selendroid.testapp");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "io.selendroid.testapp.HomeScreenActivity");

    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
 @Test
public void Sel_Button_Test() throws InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("Test Started");

    WebElement ButtonElement = driver.findElementById("io.selendroid.testapp:id/buttonStartWebview");
    ButtonElement.click();

    Thread.sleep(3000L);

    System.out.println("Test has been completed");

}


@AfterClass
public void tearDown()
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

## MainActivity.java - under first package :

```
package com.example.demo;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

## AndroidMainfest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.demo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Appiumg logs: it does not have any error reported:

> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
>   info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
>   info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"deviceName":"Lokesh Gangaiah","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"21","automationName":"Appium","language":"en","locale":"AU"}
>   info: Console LogLevel: debug

The logs in the eclipse console:

> Android Launch!
>   adb is running normally.
>   Performing com.example.myapp1.MainActivity activity launch
>   Uploading myapp1.apk onto device '00bd9781'
>   Installing myapp1.apk...
>   Success!
>   Starting activity com.example.myapp1.MainActivity on device 00bd9781
>   ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.myapp1/.MainActivity }

Comment: In your appium gui, did you give any app path??

Comment: the activity launched is not your expected activity, is it? also the logs from appium are not complete, could you share more of those

Comment: Check your package name in menifest file , activity name etc.. Both name should match in menifest file and activity class name.

Comment: @sunderkandasamy No path is specified in the appium gui

Comment: @AmeeJoshi  I have two packages under src, Frist: com.example.demo->MainActivity.java and the Second: demolaunchfirst->testthis.java. What i feel is it runs the First MainActivity.java(The default) one always. When i try to Run as->Run Configuration,Under Android Tab the radio button launch does not list the second .java file(activity),so i am unable to select that. Think so if i select the second i should be able to resolve this. Looking forward to any help pls

Comment: @Lokesh : all that said, I would assume you get to build the `apk` first for your app.

Comment: @nullpointer yes exactly,the eclipse console log says ,that its building my .apk file which is basically my first .javafile(MyActivity.java), the actual second .java file is not running(testthis.java). If i try to run that as an testNG/Junit. It gives an error as below : (this error if u google,it says to run the test as an Android Application,which i am doing and finding this problem) of not actually launching the App

Comment: Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Invalid layout of preloaded class: use -XX:+TraceClassLoading to see the origin of the problem class

Comment: You can probably get your 'how to build an android application' problem resolved on a separate thread and come back once you are done with that.

Comment: sure..thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

While providing `capabilities` to your `AppiumDriver`(in your case `AndroidDriver`) the application you want to create the automation test suite for is specified using the following capabilities, mentioned in comments assuming the value you provided are correct :

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "<path to the application>"); // adding this should help
// Specific to Android application
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "<package name of the app>"); // your case 'io.selendroid.testapp'
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "<activity name you want to launch on the app to start>"); // your case 'io.selendroid.testapp.HomeScreenActivity'
```

For further details on the capabilities you shall go through [Docs on appium.io for capabilities.](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#appium-server-capabilities)

So here is the cause of the problem, you have been using the sample package from selendroid to run your test while expecting your own built apk to show up. You can correct the following -

```
MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE : com.example.demo (line 1 from MainActivity.java and line 2 from AndroidManifest.xml)
MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY : com.example.demo.MainActivity (from manifest file again <activity android:name=".MainActivity"..../>
```

and I am expecting as you do that, you would also provide the correct path to your application directory and use the `elements` from the same package.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion will try out that, can you please let me know what will be the "<path to the application>" if i am launching from the actual device

Comment: something similar to `/Users/Lokesh/WorkingDirectory/../myApp1.apk` just guessing the path to the apk in you directory

Comment: Tried that,but still the same issue, would be very helpful for any more suggestion

Comment: could you elaborate the differences between the expected application launch(package name and activity name) and the resulting application(package name and activity name) as specified by you.

Comment: Yes, even with the above code,if i try to use the below package name and activity for for example- facebook:  com.facebook.katana    com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity. My output will be returning the hello world as mentioned in the screen shot. It should open/launch the Facebook App in my case, i dont understand why its returning hello world

Comment: would require to see more of the code to figure this out, also just leave the parameters `Package` and `AppPath` on the appium server unchecked.

Comment: Package and AppPath is unchecked.

Comment: added complete code from two .java files and the AndroidMainfest.xml. Would be looking forward to your help